# Repetitive Push Alert Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, nsdate

**Hi, I am trying to make a push alert in swift that goes off every morning at 7 AM local time (not GMT).**

Here's my code:

```
    func scheduleLocalNotification() {

        var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.timeZone = timeZone
        //localNotification.fireDate = Here is where I need help.
        localNotification.alertBody = "FooBar"
        localNotification.alertAction = "BarFoo"

    }
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to achieve code that sends a push notification every morning at 7 AM local time, rather than just once at 7:00 AM. How do I do this? Is there a NSDate object that can do this? Different code all together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `repeatInterval` field to set up a repeat and use NSCalendar to calculate the next 7 AM

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

// Calculate the next 7 AM
var date = calendar.dateBySettingHour(7, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options:nil)
if date?.timeIntervalSinceNow < 0 {
    date = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: date!, options: nil)
}
localNotification.fireDate = date

// Set up a daily repeat
localNotification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitDay
localNotification.repeatCalendar = calendar
```